# Rails 5: How do I test for uniquess at the database level when I also have validations on the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have the following join table:

```
class ContactFormUsership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact_form

  validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :contact_form_id }
end
```

It ensures that there are no duplicate `user`/`contact_form` pairings when a row is created.

I also have indexes on that table to ensure the uniquess on the db level:

```
t.index ["user_id", "contact_form_id"], name: "index_contact_form_userships_on_user_id_and_contact_form_id", unique: true
```

I have a regression test that looks like this:

```
test 'An error is raised if a user is added to a form more than once' do
  contact_form = ContactForm.create
  user = users(:user_1)

  assert_raises(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) do
    2.times do
      contact_form.users << user
    end
  end
end
```

But this does not test that it is not possible to create duplicate rows at the db level. It only tests the validations.

How do I test uniqueness at a db level? Is there any way to `<<` without validations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to test the behavior of your ContactFormUsership table, you would do something like:

```
test 'An error is raised if a user is added to a form more than once' do
  contact_form = ContactForm.create
  user = users(:user_1)

  assert_raises(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid) do
    c1 = ContactFormUsership.new(user: user, contact_form: contact_form)
    c1.save
    c2 = ContactFormUsership.new(user: user, contact_form: contact_form)
    c2.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

You can find out more about validate: false  at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. The error that needs to be checked here is `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`.